# Access Denied to all SVN Directories

Tags: svn, windows-vista

I'm trying to delete several working copy directories, but I get an Access Denied on all the SVN files, running as admin or normal user.  I've killed the Tortoise cache process, and cannot figure what is wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download Microsoft's [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and see what processes have the file-handles open.

Once you've downloaded Process Explorer run it (no install required), and

- Select Find -> Find Handle or DLL
- Enter a filename you can't delete.

It will list the processes with handles to that file. Kill the process and you should be ok.

Note that this is a general Windows answer, not a TortoiseSVN specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reboot your PC first before trying to delete it again.

Or maybe this tool can help: [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)

> Unlocker is the solution to the
>   following types of Windows error
>   messages
>
> ```
> * Cannot delete folder: It is being used by another person or
> ```
>
> program
>       * Cannot delete file: Access is denied
>       * There has been a sharing violation.
>       * The source or destination file may be in use.
>       * The file is in use by another program or user.
>       * Make sure the disk is not full or write-protected and that the file
>   is not currently in use.
>
> 1. Simply right click the folder or file and select Unlocker
> 2. If the folder or file is locked, a window listing of lockers will appear
> 3. Simply click Unlock All and you are done!

Answer (score 1):

I had heinous problems with this until I disabled my Norton Autoprotect anti-virus software.

http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#windows-access-denied

SO posting tip: include version, OS, etc. of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar access denied issue when trying to move a repo from another server. I was able to load the repo by doing the following.

- Create the new repo using `svnadmin create C:\RepoDirectory\RepoName`
- Ensure that your user account has "Owner" privileges of the folder you are trying to execute on. Right click the properties and go into the advanced security settings.
- Execute your svnadmin load command
- `svnadmin load C:\RepoDirectory\RepoName < C:\LocationOf\RepoDump.dmp`